# Inside Subclassed UITableViewCell Override Func LayoutSubviews Being Called Double

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell that has is having `override func layoutSubviews()` called twice for each cell. This is creating multiple copies of elements within the cell.

The UITableView returns the proper count of cells and displays the correct number of cells but the layout function resets a handful of properties to nil. Therefore rendering a lot of the data incorrectly.

TableView Inside UIViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userMatches.count    // return 2 correctly
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    return self.view.bounds.height * 0.20

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: MatchTableViewCell = self.matchTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("matchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MatchTableViewCell

    cell.matchDetails = userMatches[indexPath.row]
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell // creates 2 correctly

}
```

UITableView Subclass:

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

// runs 4 times

    let userHelperIconArray = [userZoom, userTakeTwo, userStopper]
    let opponentHelperIconArray = [opponentZoom, opponentTakeTwo, opponentStopper]

    layoutHelperInventoryIcons(self, opponentHelperIconArray: opponentHelperIconArray, userHelperIconArray: userHelperIconArray, opponentNameLabel: opponentName)
    layoutMiniGameboard(self)

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    print("one")

    turnIdentifier(self, matchDetails: matchDetails, opponentNameLabel: opponentName)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should 't be doing this in `layoutSubviews` anyway. Instead, move the configuration to a separate method, and have your table view data source call that configuration method after dequeing the cell.

Comment: Agreed. `layoutSubviews` exists to update subviews' positions when a view changes its state or bounds. You should expect that this method could be called many times. It's performance is also important because a slow `layoutSubviews` will block the main thread and prevent the app from redrawing so you should try to avoid repeating unnecessary work here.